# Chart Labels design in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

[image]
I want to design something like this for my graph. With my code, I achieved something like this.

[image]
The text is not aligned center with vertical lines. May my approach towards achieving this be completely wrong. Any help is appreciated.

I used the following code.

```
struct FirstFormatterIndicator: View {
    var text: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            Rectangle().frame(width: 1, height: 5)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            Text(text)
                .font(.system(size: 9))
        }
    }
}

struct EndFormatterLabel: View {
    var text: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 0) {
            HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
                Rectangle().frame(height: 1)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                Rectangle().frame(width: 1, height: 5)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
            }
            Text(text)
                .font(.system(size: 9))
        }
    }
}

struct WeeklyFormatterView: View {
    var texts = ["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S"]
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            FirstFormatterIndicator(text: texts.first!)
            HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(1..<texts.count, id: \.self) { index in
                    EndFormatterLabel(text: texts[index])
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `.offset` modifier. For example, this will shift all of the letters to the right by 10:

```swift
struct FirstFormatterIndicator: View {
    var text: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            Rectangle().frame(width: 1, height: 5)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            Text(text)
                .font(.system(size: 9))
        }
    }
}

struct EndFormatterLabel: View {
    var text: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 0) {
            HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
                Rectangle().frame(height: 1)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                Rectangle().frame(width: 1, height: 5)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
            }
            Text(text)
                .font(.system(size: 9))
                .offset(x:10, y:0) //<-- HERE!
//This will accept X and Y offset values, along with giving a CGSize.
//You can also use the .position modifier, but this will set position, 
//and it is not relative
        }
    }
}

struct WeeklyFormatterView: View {
    var texts = ["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S"]
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            FirstFormatterIndicator(text: texts.first!)
            HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(1..<texts.count, id: \.self) { index in
                    EndFormatterLabel(text: texts[index])
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

See the documentation for the `offset` modifier here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/offset(x:y:)

And the article from Apple on how to make minute adjustements to views: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/making-fine-adjustments-to-a-view-s-position

However, it looks like your `S` text could actually be moved a little to the left. This code would work:

```swift
struct FirstFormatterIndicator: View {
    var text: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            Rectangle().frame(width: 1, height: 5)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            Text(text)
                .font(.system(size: 9))
        }
    }
}

struct EndFormatterLabel: View {
    var text: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 0) {
            HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
                Rectangle().frame(height: 1)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                Rectangle().frame(width: 1, height: 5)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
            }
            Text(text)
                .font(.system(size: 9))
                .offset(x:text != "S" ? 10 : -5, y:0) //<-- HERE!
//You can adjust these values as needed
//Example using a CGSize below
//.offset(CGSize(width: text != "S" ? 10 : -5, height: 0))
//This is from Apple's Docs - see full example below
        }
    }
}

struct WeeklyFormatterView: View {
    var texts = ["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S"]
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            FirstFormatterIndicator(text: texts.first!)
            HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(1..<texts.count, id: \.self) { index in
                    EndFormatterLabel(text: texts[index])
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

And the example of using `.offset` from [Apple's Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/offset(_:)) with a `CGSize` is on [this link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/offset(_:)).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, the text will vary in different cases. When we display yearly graphs, we should show months which has bigger text. So, Looking for an ideal solution that suits any text.

Comment: OK. Also, just a tip - instead of using an index, just do a ForEach with the variable inside it. For example: `ForEach(texts, id:\.self){ text in }`. This will remove the need for indexing. The text object inside will contain what you need. This won't fix the layout but makes your code more safe - no out of range errors.